# knockout bindings multiple viewModels in magento 2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, magento2

I've been using the following code to bind viewModels in other projects, and had to modify it a bit for magento 2. Maybe I've just been looking at it too long but heres my issue.

In the following snippet I get the  error Cannot set property 'categoryViewModel' of undefined although logging it out it seems like it should be defined. Any ideas out there?

demoController.js

```
define('js/theme',[
    'jquery',
    'knockout',
    'category',
    'product',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, ko, categoryView, productView) {
'use strict';

var demoController = {
    init: function(){

        var self = this;
        var shouter = new ko.subscribable();

        categoryView.categoryViewController(shouter);
        productView.productViewController(shouter);

        self.masterVM = (function(){                      
            this.categoryViewModel = new categoryView.categoryViewModel();
            this.productViewModel = new productView.productViewModel();
        })();

        ko.applyBindings(self.masterVM);  

    }
};

demoController.init();
});
```

categoryView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'knockout'
], function($, ko) {

var categoryView = {
    categoryViewController: function(shouter){
        //var self = this;
        this.categoryViewModel = function(){
            this.foo = ko.observable('category!');

            console.log('category view', this.foo() );
        };    
    }
};
return categoryView;
});
```

Comment: 'use strict'; was the issue, but as I continue to learn, magento 2 has abstracted knockout a bit with their own utils and way of implementing so this question is invalid since this is not the correct way to implement(whichI 'm still trying to figure out)

Comment: saw this get a upvote, if anyone stumbles across this I did find the solution https://github.com/digital-pollution/magedemo although it was a while ago and theres probably a better way to achieve this now